# SonarQube configuration in the Oracle Jet project

Tags: sonarqube, oracle-jet

I'm trying to configure my Oracle JET based project to the sonar qube. On executing `sonar-scanner` command I ended up with following error:

```
ERROR: Language of file 'src\js\path_mapping.json' can not be decided as the file matches patterns of both sonar.lang.patterns.gscan.t13y : **/*.wptg,**/*.properties,**/*.rts,**/*.xlf,**/*.xliff,**/*.xrts,**/*.dlf,**/*.msg,**/*.resx,**/*.rc,**/*.yaml,**/*.yml,**/*.json,**/*.txt,**/*.strings and sonar.lang.patterns.json : **/*.json
```

I tried to override the files association by setting up the following in project properties file:

```
sonar.json.file.suffixes=.json
```

This couldn't help either. Getting the same error again.
As I don't have access to sonar admin module, I need to achieve it though project properties only.

Is there any other way to fix it? I did not find any concrete answer anywhere.

Comment: not sure if that is possible but  did you try to overwrite `sonar.lang.patterns.json`  to not match the same ending as `sonar.lang.patterns.gscan.t13y` - that should actually be possible.

Comment: @SimonSchrottner could you please guide me how can I do that?